# Classify the two lists using jQuery

Tags: jquery, list

I am using jQuery. Now I need to classify the two lists. If any list having an Id starts with outer, I need to alert it as "Outer". If any list having an Id starts with sub, I need to alert it as "Sub".

```
<ul id="nav">
     <li id="outer1"><a href="#url"><b class="">Outer 1</b></a></li>
     <li id="outer2"><a href="#url"><b class="">Outer 2</b></a></li>

     <li id="outer3"><a href="#url"><b class="">Outer 3  </b></a>
          <ul style="display: none;">
             <li id="sub1"><a href="#url"><span id="inner1"> inner1</span></a></li>
             <li id="sub2"><a href="#url"><span id="inner2"> inner2</span></a></li>

         </ul>
     </li>
     <li id="outer4"><a href="#url"><b class="">Outer 3  </b></a></li>
</ul>
```

My code is below. I done the following code.

```
$("li").each(function(){
      $( "li[ @id ^= 'start' ]" )
           alert("START");
        $( "li[ @id ^= 'sub' ]" )
           alert("SUB");
 });
```

What change should I make in order to execute correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("li").each(function()
{ 
    if($(this).is("[id^='start']")) alert("START");
    else if($(this).is("[id^='sub']")) alert("SUB");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to distinguish between the first and second level list items, you can also simply use **$("li li")** for the second level and something like **$("li:not(li li)")** for the first level (not tested).

Answer (score 0):

```
$("li").each(function(){ 
    $( "li[ @id ^= 'start' ]" )
```

In the `each` loop, you have to make use of `this` keyword. So, each `LI` is `this`. For what are you trying to do, if I was you, I would do it like this:

```
$("li").each(function(){ 
    $(this).is('[id^=start]')
})
```

However, I guess you better re-think your rationale. Because I don't think you will need all those `ID`'s. For selecting the first level of `LI`, you can use this:

```
$('ul > li')
```

Then, for the next level you can use

```
$('ul > ul > li')
```

And so on.